# How to use Spring AMQP to read messages in a queue?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Given a queue that has messages, how do I use Spring AMQP get all the messages stored in that queue? Note, the question to not asking how to listen to a queue.

Comment: Did you try http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#receiving-messages

Comment: @GermannArlington Yes, and I cannot find it there. The closest thing mentioned there is using `AmqpTemplate`'s `receive(String queueName)` method which returns only one message.

Comment: You may misunderstand the concept and the idea behind message delivery mechanism: it guarantees delivery of every message (separately) so it has to provide functionality to `receive()` one message  at-a-time, there is no way to fail just few messages out of your batch otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I don't see any sense in such a solution. It is really better to **listen** to the queue for all messages. If you need something like **browse** - get and requeue (or `nack`), then yes `AmqpTemplate.receive()` is good choice. You should wrap that invocation to the TX (e.g. just with `RabbitTransactionManager`), do `while(true)` until `receive()` returns messages and `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly()` in the end.

Comment: My use case is  to display the queued messages in the UI and allow the user to select which message they want to process.

Comment: Well, it isn't possible. It doesn't fit to messaging and queuing concept and principle. Queue isn't like a table in Data Base: you can consume message or not, but there is no any **select** options. With that it won't be **queue**.